# WebView crash while using setDrawsBackground in awakeFromNib

Tags: cocoa, webkit, webview, nsview

I have a local property which is an IBOutlet to a WebView in the NIB.
For one user, a really really important one I may say it crashed but have
not found any other users with the same crash.

The stacktrace I got back:

```
Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSView setDrawsBackground:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101849380'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff883097b4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8859f0f3 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88363110 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff882db91f ___forwarding___ + 751
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff882d7a68 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
    5   NZBVortex                           0x00000001000521d8 -[SearchResultViewController awakeFromNib] + 55
```

My code from the ViewController which contains the WebKit WebView:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {

    [self.descriptionView setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [[[self.descriptionView mainFrame] frameView] setAllowsScrolling:NO];
...
}
```

I have no clue anymore how to fix this because I can't reproduce locally.
It's just a View I am use setDrawsBackground on.

Should I wait for a WebViewDelegate method to be fired or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too stupid. After readding the webkit framework
It worked again. It seemed a switch between Xcode versions it just broke. 
It resulted in that a normal nsview was loaded in the place where the webkit view supposed to be (defaulted)

Answer (score 0):

Set that after the window has been loaded. If you try to change it while the webview is updating it may cause problems.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable explanation. I've overloaded NSViewControllers' -(void)loadView and did the stuff there. Now waiting for feedback. Thanks so far.

Comment: the question is only useful if the solution actually gets posted, HERE.  Yes, this is a place to get help, but the point is to have a record of the solutions, not to just get _our problems_ solved....  Want this to turn into Expert's Exchange, lol?  Can you explain your fix that you mentioned `I've overloaded NSViewControllers' -(void)loadView`"

Comment: That was not the solution alex gray, i was just stating we ALREADY overloaded the loadView. Which was not the root problem of this crash. Because of a bug in Xcode the IB file got damaged somehow in such a way the Xcode forgot that the WebView was a web view and thus revert to a normal View - so that's why it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what OS version they're using? The documentation says only OS X v10.4.11 and later support the `setDrawsBackground:` method on a WebView.

Comment: They are using 10.6.6, which I also use. I think ExitToShell is on to something though. Thanks for your answer though.